# Spring Boot passes test case that should fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have added a test case in my Spring Boot application. However, when I `./gradlew build`, all the test cases pass. Any reason?

```
@Test
public void testIntentionalError() throws Exception {
    boolean thrown = true;
    assertThat(!thrown);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that this testcase is being run. You can have some config files which define a subset of testcases to be run.

Comment: I am sure they are being run, because after the build, the reports index.html shows all the test cases as passed and in green!

Comment: Try `assertThat(!thrown).isTrue();`

Comment: And why would you need such a test? Are you testing `boolean` values assignment works well within a *JVM*?

Comment: @tmarwen No. I had a function which I was certain returns false for a certain input.  So instead of the false, there was a function call. I just removed it to make the code more readable.

Comment: What `assertThat` import is being used? `Assertations` packages or `Junit`'s assertThat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your test doesn't test anything.

Try this :

```
@Test
public void testIntentionalError() throws Exception {
    boolean thrown = true;
    assertTrue(!thrown);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am coding at 5 am so I absolutely didn't see that!

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like the following (in case you want to use the assertThat method):

```
@Test
public void testIntentionalError() throws Exception {
    boolean thrown = true;
    assertThat(!thrown, is(true));
}
```

using hamcrest matcher (import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is)